# Migrating to Bootstrap v4 caused a table to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

I wrote my code in Bootstrap v3, however, upon realising that it doesn't support Spinners and many of the CSS elements I've envisioned didn't have the style that I wanted, I want to switch to Bootstrap v4. I added all of the required scripts / css links to the head, however I noticed that one whole table from my code has frankly just disappeared. And I have no idea why. The table is on a separate html element, and works in Bootstrap v3 but not sure why it's not displaying with v4.

Code:

main2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header" style="background-color: white; width:100%; height:auto; position:fixed;">
    <p id="statusText">Preparing supermarkets from Google Drive...</p>

    <div id="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search by Name or ID of Supermarket"/> 
    </div> 
  </div>

    <!-- <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <div class="spinner-border" id="spinner" role="status">
    </div> -->
  </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="addsupermarket" style="" class=""></div>
      </div>

  <div id="foot" style="background-color:white; width:100%; height:auto; position:fixed; top:447px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;" id="btnAdd">Add Supermarkets</button>
  </div>




  
  <script>  
    var data;
    var checkedItems = new Map();

    function loadView(options) {
      var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "addsupermarket" : options.id;
      var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} : options.callback;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html) {
        document.getElementById("addsupermarket").innerHTML = html;
        typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);

      })[options.func]();
    }
    function setDataForSearch() {
      checkedItems = new Map();
      showSpinner();
      document.getElementById("statusText").innerHTML = "Loading..."
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned) {
        data = dataReturned.slice();
        var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
        var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
        var template = templateBox.content;

        data.forEach(function(r) {
        var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
        var supermarketCheckColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketCheck");
        var supermarketNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketName");
        var supermarketIDColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketID");
        var supermarketStatusColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketStatus");
        var supermarketCheckbox = tr.querySelector(".supermarketCheckbox");
        supermarketNameColumn.textContent = r[0];
        supermarketIDColumn.textContent = r[1];
        supermarketStatusColumn.textContent = r[2];
        supermarketCheckbox.dataset.supermarketID = r[1];
        searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
        });
        document.getElementById("statusText").innerHTML = "Found " + data.length + " results";
        hideSpinner();
      }).getDataForSearch();
    }

    function loadAddSupermarketView() {
      loadView({func: "loadAddSupermarketView", callback: setDataForSearch});
    }
    loadAddSupermarketView();
    document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("input", inputEventHandler);
    function inputEventHandler(e) {
      if (e.target.matches("#searchInput")) {
        search();
      }
    }

    function showSpinner() {
      document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hideSpinner() {
      document.getElementById("spinner").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    
    function search() {
      var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
      var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r) {
        return (r[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1 || (r[1].toString().indexOf(searchInput.toString()) !== -1));
      });
      document.getElementById("statusText").innerHTML = "Loading..."
      var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
      var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
      var template = templateBox.content;
      searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";
      resultsArray.forEach(function(r) {
        var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
        var supermarketCheckbox = tr.querySelector(".supermarketCheckbox");
        var supermarketCheckColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketCheck");
        var supermarketNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketName");
        var supermarketIDColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketID");
        var supermarketStatusColumn = tr.querySelector(".supermarketStatus");
        supermarketCheckbox.dataset.supermarketID = r[1];
        supermarketNameColumn.textContent = r[0];
        supermarketIDColumn.textContent = r[1];
        supermarketStatusColumn.textContent = r[2];
        searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
        });
        document.getElementById("statusText").innerHTML = "Found " + resultsArray.length + " results";      
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

addsupermarket.html (which contains the table)

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Add?</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="searchResults">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like your <div> and </div> elements are not bracketing properly.  Look at `class="spinner-border"` and `class="container"`

Comment: Many thanks, the table shows now. However, the items in each column are showing up in its individual rows. See edits

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean, what your problem is? And your scripts are so complex and unreproducable that it is impossible for me to know what to look for.  Perhaps show what you get and an example of what you want to get.  And where you think in the code its failing.  I typically put alerts in and make sure the data is what I expect it to be.

Comment: The edit looks to be a different question (the first one was about a missing table, now it's about the page layout), since you already received a helpful comment you should post a new question focused on the new problem and including a clear description of expected layout and the steps that you followed to do the migration from one version to the other.